# How to concatenate index value with ngModel using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using a dynamic table with angular material. Each row within the table has a select dropdown field. By default the button which is present adjacent to the dropdown field is disabled. When the user selects any of the option from the dropdown the button should automatically become clickable.

However, I'm getting an error pointing to this code `(ngModelChange)="'isDisabled'+i=$event"`:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="job-id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        <mat-form-field class="job-id-field">
          <mat-select (change)="onSelectJobId($event)" (ngModelChange)="'isDisabled'+i=$event" placeholder="Select Job ID" [ngModel]="'isDisabled'+i" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let job_id of element.job_id" [value]="job_id.job_id_id">
              {{ job_id.job_id_id }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

     <!-- Manage Tabs Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="manage-tabs">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <button *ngIf="!showArchivedBrand" mat-button [disabled]="'isDisabled'+i" [routerLink]="[element.id, 'manage-tabs']">Manage Tabs</button>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Brand Guidelines Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="brand-guidelines">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button *ngIf="!showArchivedBrand" mat-button [routerLink]="[element.id, 'guidelines']">Guidelines</button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: How is `isDisabled...` declared? Is it a list of variables?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an object to a string literal. `(ngModelChange)="'isDisabled'+i=$event"` when i is 1 for example would work out to the statement `'isDisabled1' = $event`.

Ideally, this 'disabled' property would be part of the table data for each row, and you could simply bind to that e.g. `[disabled]="element.disabled"`.

Since you are merely trying to enable the button when any value is selected from the select, you don't actually need any model to do that. Simply assign a template reference to the select component, and use that to check for a value.

```
<mat-select #jobIDSelect (change)="onSelectJobId($event)" placeholder="Select Job ID" required>

...
<button *ngIf="!showArchivedBrand" mat-button [disabled]="jobIDSelect.value" ... >Manage Tabs</button>
```

You may need a model for the Job ID select as well, I'm not sure, but maybe you are taking care of that via `(change)="onSelectJobId($event)"`.